# After update to Kubuntu 18.10, telegram file selector has encoding issues

Tags: kde, 18.10, telegram

After upgrading Kubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10, I get the following picture, when trying to share a file via telegram:

[image: picture with destroyed utf characters]

Telegram is installed from the telegram site.

Comment: Someone else seems to have a similar issue reported here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2406056 (https://i.imgur.com/6j0CsG3.png)